# FX Statistical Arbitrage Strategy

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, statistics, fx, arbitrage

I have had experience creating stat arb strategies for equities and etfs, but haven't dabbled much into FX trading. I was wondering if anyone knew any resources online they would suggest, or could lend their intuition as to how they would go about determining whether a currency is over/undervalued purely from the data alone. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi AliveTrickster, welcome to Quant.SE! This is very broad and too much asking for a trading strategy.

Comment: My http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/716 may or may not help.

Comment: Generally quant strategies in FX can be classified as Value (based on PPP and other econ fundamentals), Carry (based on interest rate differences) and Momentum (based on past price trends).